# `No Unique Constraint` error on Django ForiegnKey w/ unique PK

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, google-cloud-platform

There are dozens of similar posts, but typically the OP isn't relying on the built-in, auto-incrementing, and already-unique PK value so they tend to have the same answers. None have answered my question.

I keep getting this error when running `python manage.py migrate` on my (Django/Postgres) production Google Cloud server:

> django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "api_bookgroup"

I understand that the error is saying "Hey! I don't know which record to return, because there's no unique identifier" BUT two things have me scratching my head:

1. [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.to_field) are pretty clear that "By default, Django uses the primary key of the related object" - so the PK should be the unique constraint that's required.
2. This same code runs perfectly on 3 other dev machines/databases, including our Google Cloud dev instance (Although each other instance has different data in the database)

Point #2 makes me wonder if it's possible for Django/Postgres to somehow allow two `bookGroup` records with the same PK without throwing terrible errors? if that's the case, how would I find those records, and if not, What else could be causing this error?

**Thanks for your Help!**

```html
# api.models.py

class BookGroup(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='')
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    ...
    
class HistBookGroup(HistoricalRecord):
    master_id = models.ForeignKey(BookGroup, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='historical_data')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='')
    ...
```

```
class HistBookGroup(HistoricalRecord):
    master_id = models.ForeignKey(BookGroup, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='historical_data')
    updated_by_user_id = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='hist_bookgroups_updated')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, Turns out that although Django was keeping a PK column and auto-incrementing it for the `bookgroups` table, that Somehow the default `is_unique` and `is_PrimaryKey` values for the PK column were switched off. No idea how or when, but closer inspection into the table with DataGrip helped reveal that. and now the error makes total sense.

I'll leave this post up to help any other poor souls struggling with this issue.